# Display image to right of TextView in RelativeLayout API16 onward

Tags: android, textview, imageview

I can't seem to be able to display an image onto the right of a TextView in a RelativeLayout.
The following seems to work on older APIs, but on API16 or newer does not work.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spacer4"
        android:layout_width="10dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/check1"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_width="44dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingEnd="10dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: check android:drawableRight  property for textview

Answer (score 0):

Change the textview code like this.The issue may be with referencing wrong id for the views

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spacer4"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/check1"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_width="44dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/label1"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:paddingEnd="10dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
```